# Python/Pandas - drop_duplicates selecting the most complete row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with people information. However sometimes these guys get repeated and some rows have more info about the same person than the others. Is there a way to drop the duplicates using column 'Name' as reference but only keep the most filled rows?

Comment: Provide a sample data and expected output out of it. Text alone questions for data-related questions are not a reasonable ones.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a',np.nan,np.nan,'M'],['a',12,np.nan,'M'],['c',np.nan,np.nan,'M'],['d',np.nan,np.nan,'M']],columns=['Name','Age','Region','Gender'])
```

Sorting rows based on nan count and dropping duplicates with subset 'Name' by keep first one might help i.e.

```
df['count'] = pd.isnull(df).sum(1)
df= df.sort_values(['count']).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'],keep='first').drop('count',1)
```

Output:

Before:

```
  Name   Age  Region Gender  
0    a   NaN     NaN      M  
1    a  12.0     NaN      M  
2    c   NaN     NaN      M  
3    d   NaN     NaN      M
```

After:

```
Name   Age  Region Gender
1    a  12.0     NaN      M
2    c   NaN     NaN      M
3    d   NaN     NaN      M
```